# What is happening to the VtC queue?

Tags: discussion, voting

As we can see, the VtC queue is around 200 since a long time. Its daily stats show a very low activity. It seems, the 3k+ users of the site produce a much lower review activity as they had to.

Other SE sites, for example, the StackOverflow have a similar problem, but there at least a little VtC activity exist.

I think it is an independent problem if there would be some disagreement about the VtC rules - I think the OPs would require a quick decision about their questions, and a quick feedback and advices, how to improve.

Why is it so? Is it okay?

I think the logical thing to do if I start to build it down. Around 2 weeks is enough to get the queue size to zero. But doing this alone is not very fruitful, at least 3 or 5 votes were needed for a decision (3 leave open or 5 closure votes). If only I give a vote to all of them, I think it doesn't help too much.

What is going on, what should I (we) do?

Comment: Apparently, if one of the most active close vote reviewers mostly stops reviewing, then the queue grows and grows.

Comment: @Ward Thanks :-) In my case, there was an external constraint, too. But I was only one, and a decision requires 3-5 voters.